# Emails automatically saving to exchange

Tags: exchange, outlook, microsoft-office-365

I have a user who when they open a .msg file from the file server with Outlook if they close the file it asks if they want to save. If the user hits the no button the email is then saved to the user's email account in exchange. Does anyone know how this can happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did the user encounter the same issue when he open/closed .msg files on other clients?

Based on my knowledge and test, if we open a .msg file with Outlook and then close the message window, normally we will not receive the save request.

Please try to start Outlook with safe mode, if the issue doesn't appear any more, maybe some add-ins and vba scripts caused this issue, and you could try to disable them, then re-open the .msg file again to check the result.

Comment: I will mark this as the answer as unfortunately the issue went away after a reboot of Outlook. I assume it was something with an add-in acting up, but have no way to test at this point. Thank you for your answer, I will give that a try if this comes up again.